# Dynamically count number of tables up to certain point in the document

Tags: vba, count, ms-word

I have this report that has many tables and I want to dynamically count the number of tables in order to get this result:

```
| faa | fee | fii | foo | foo |
| you | get | the | idea| ... |
```

**Table num 1** - table title

```
| faa | fee | fii | foo | foo |
| you | get | the | idea| ... |
```

**Table num 2** - table title

I would like to automatize the proccess so I could have something like this:

**Table num** `{$numberOfTablesSoFar}`

Can it be done?

Comment: So what's wrong with using table captions? In any event, your question isn't a programming one. As such it is off-topic for StackOverflow and should be asked in an appropriate end-user forum (e.g. MS Answers).

Comment: @macropod - I want to use table captions, but I want Word to dinamically set its number, this way I could add a table at the beginning of the file, and the remaining captions would increment one number.
For what I've searched, Word supports scripting and vba, that's why I posted it here

Comment: No scripting or VBA required. Do a Google or Bing search for "word insert caption table"

Comment: « want to use table captions, but I want Word to dinamically set its number, this way I could add a table at the beginning of the file, and the remaining captions would increment one number.» Which is precisely what table captions do. Clearly, then, you aren't using table captions...

Comment: @Timothy Rylatt Thank you! Didn't know that was a thing

Comment: @macropod I thought you meant writing down table captions manually, didn't realize you were asking me to use a feature I didn't know its existence

Comment: References>Insert Caption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other users already mentioned, I just need to go to the References Tab and click on Insert Caption. No coding required.